# Regex - Check if multiple patterns apply to string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have a set of patterns and I want to check if all of them apply to at least one character in a string. The patterns I am using are: `[a-z]`,`[A-Z]`,`[0-9]` and `[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]`. I plan to assemble these into a basic `if statement` such as:

```
If ((pattern1,pattern2,pattern3).test(string) == true) {
    //Do Something
}
```

For example, if I were to use the string `dA2#`, it would return true since all of the patterns apply to the string, however, if I were to use the string `svI2`, it would return false since only 3 of the 4 patterns apply.

Please keep in mind that I am new to regex and am not fully familiar with how all of the operators work.

Comment: I'd use [`^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[ a-zA-Z\d-]*[^ a-zA-Z\d-])\D*\d`](https://regex101.com/r/rfgwpP/1) which might look a bit long but it is far more efficient to use [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) before the required character then `.*` (reduce backtracking). Also the pattern should be anchored to start `^` for only triggering the lookaheads once. And one last point is that  you only need three lookaheads, one condition can just be *matched*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `(?=.*[a-z])`. String multiple together like this: `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])`

```js
check("a") // does not match
check("aA") // does not match
check("aA1") // does not match
check("aA1&") // matches
check("&Aa1") // matches

function check (string) {
  if (/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9- ])/.test(string)) {
    console.log("matches", string)
  } else {
    console.log("does not match", string)
  }
}
```

Comment: What I want is that but I only want it to return true when the string matches all of the patterns, whereas that returns true when it matches any one of the patterns.

Comment: @Sheep That is what it does. It only returns true if all of the patterns match. I edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: When I tried the one before it would return true when it met any one of the patterns but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the function `every`:

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

[Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

In our case, it will look like this:

```js
const patterns = [
  ".*[a-z]",
  ".*[A-Z]",
  ".*[0-9]",
  ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]"
]

const check = (source, patterns) =>
  patterns.every(pattern => new RegExp(pattern).test(source));

console.log("dA2#", check("dA2#", patterns))
console.log("svI2", check("svI2", patterns))
console.log("aBcD123", check("aBcD123", patterns))
console.log("&Aa1", check("&Aa1", patterns))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest allowing any character before and after your patterns. So that means your regex matches anything until the first of your patterns is found. Then again, any string can occur until the first match of your second pattern and so on. You can watch this in detail in this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VhKXGB/1) (a regex debugger that has nice explaining features).

You can do so by adding `.*`. `.` matches any character, `*` enforces the beforegoing pattern to be present, zero, one or multiple times. Your pattern then looks like this:

```
.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[0-9].*[^a-zA-Z0-9- ].*
```

```js
const pattern = /.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[0-9].*[^a-zA-Z0-9- ].*/;

console.log("Does 'dA2#' match:", pattern.test("dA2#"));
console.log("Does 'svI2' match:", pattern.test("svI2"));

// order is important, inverted first example does not match!
console.log("Does '#2Ad' match:", pattern.test("#2Ad"));
```

Note that this assumes that you want to match the first pattern at first, the second should be the next and so on.

---

*Relating to @RichardHenage's anwser*

Using `(?=.*<your pattern>)` to concatenate patterns does work but is not what this construct is designed for. `.*` simply adds any character, just as I suggested. But using `(?=...)` is an advanced non-standard technique. It is not necessary here and just "overpowered" and useless.

The `(?=...)` construct is the so called [look ahead assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Assertions). This means that the regexp will look ahead, to the next upcoming text. The regex will only match, if the next text matches the expression in the look ahead assertion. This is useful if you want ensure that your match is at the correct position but you do not want to select it completely, e.g. when replacing.

Example: Replace all "bar"s in all "foobar"s but not when there is no foo before.

```js
const pattern = /foo(?=bar)/g;

const text = "bar foobar foo bar foobar foo bar";

console.log("Original text:", text);
console.log("Replaced text:", text.replace(pattern, "---"));
```

So when taking a look at @RichardHenage's answer again, the pattern matches nothing which then must be followed (=look ahead assertion) by your patterns. I think this is not what you inted to do.

I think since you are a beginner, you should not use this answer or at least know about what it means. `(?=...)` is NOT how to concatenate. It works but it is way more than only concatenating.

---

*Relating to @aloisdg's answer*

I personally also would not use `every`. This is iterating over patterns. While sometimes there is no other choice, it is possible in your case to write only one RegExp expression. And I personally think that the iteration makes your code less readable. You want to check if a string has a certain format and that is clearly visible when using one single regexp that should match a text (but I think this is personal taste). Plus using multiple expressions requires multiple compilings of the pattern to a `RegExp` object (which could be avoided by caching them) and multiple RegExp search executions (not avoidable).

For more or more complicated RegExp patterns I have to admit that it is sometimes more readable to split them into multiple steps.

Also note that the order of your patterns is not fixed in this approach.